# .htaccess Rewrite url works but I have conflicts with some pages

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am using the following .htaccess rule to make www.site.com/index.php convert into www.site.com/username

It's working pretty well but I am having problem with some pages **I can't access for example other pages in the same directory, like *settings.php***  only index.php acess is allowed. also I am having problem with a dropdown menu build with bootstrap in the same dir I am using include_once("menu.php"); in the index.php file the menu is showed but dropdown list is not showed.

**I tested the menu without the .htacesss and dropdown works ok, I think the main problem is the .htaccess file**, how to solve this?

Any alternative to my .htaccess code?

**Here is the .htaccess code**

```html
# .htaccess
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9-_.]+)/?$ index.php?id=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9-_.]+)/([a-z0-9]+)/?$ index.php?id=$1&goto=$2 [NC,L]
```

**Here is the menu.php code**

```html
<li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle"><?php echo $_SESSION["username"]; ?> <b class="caret"></b></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu" style="background-color: #333; color:white;">
                            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-home" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp;<?php echo $lang['MENU_HOME']; ?></a></li>
                            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp;<?php echo $lang ['PROFILE']; ?></a></li>
                            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp;<?php echo $lang ['SHOOPING_CART']; ?></a></li>
                            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp;<?php echo $lang ['SEARCH']; ?></a></li>
                            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-envelope" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp;<?php echo $lang ['MESSAGES']; ?></a></li>
                            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-cog" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp;<?php echo $lang ['SETTINGS']; ?></a></li>

                            <li class="divider"></li>
                            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-sign-out" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp;<?php echo $lang ['SIGN-OUT']; ?></a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
```

Comment: RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-s you should be able to use RewriteCond to prevent application of RewriteRules for existing files.

Comment: Explain me more? what should I change in the .htaccess file?

Comment: Is all the PHP in the same directory?

Comment: Yes It's in the same directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the menu problem this way:

insted of add

```
include_once("menu.php");
```

I included the menu code direct in the page.
The redirect problem I solved using javascript, insted of

```
header("Location: page.php)";
```

I did this

```html
<?php 
echo'<script> window.location = "page.php";</script>'; 
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

The **RewriteCond**s check if the request URL is a file, directory or symlink, and if so (the default is AND), the first rewrite will fail.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-s
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9-_.]+)/?$ index.php?id=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9-_.]+)/([a-z0-9]+)/?$ index.php?id=$1&goto=$2 [NC,L]
```

If it is a page like **settings.php**, the second rule will also fail.

Comment: Yes It works, but I am still having the same problem with the dropdown menu :/

Comment: Could you use view source and post that?  We can't see the HTML.

Comment: the code is the same in the menu.php file it works when I ctrl+u but the dropdown is not working  , It shows only the username in menu but the dropdown is not opening It's werid because I can see all the dropdown menu code in inpect element but dropdown is not opening, it works if I delete the .htaccess file or go to other page , and also it works when visit www.site.com/user/ without the index.php in the end of the url.

Comment: I am also having another in the **index.php**

I can't use `header("Location: page.php");` it's not redirecting :/

Comment: Hello guys I copied this code but I have a problem if some of you can help please help me, here is my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43895224/make-htaccess-rule-apply-only-to-the-current-folder